# Algorithm Run Time Matrix

Tags: performance, algorithm

I am having trouble figuring out the tight bound and the lower bound for this pseudocode. Could anyone help ?

```
Array S;

for i <-- 0 to n-1
  for j <-- 0 to n-1 
    for k <-- 0 to n-1 
       M[i][j] = M1[i][k]*M2[k][j]
return M
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might be better off at http://cs.stackexchange.com/ with this question.

Answer (score 4):

Three nested loops and no options to end early would mean a complexity of n^3, best and worst case are the same.